# Preparing _tkinter and sqlite3 for Python installation (no admin rights)

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to build Python directly from source code, with no admin rights, and after running:

> export CPPFLAGS='-I/opt/sqlite-3.7.16.2/include -I/opt/tk8.6.0/include
>     -I/opt/tcl8.6.0/include/'
>
> export LDFLAGS='-L/opt/sqlite-3.7.16.2/lib -L/opt/tk8.6.0/lib/
>   -L/opt/tcl8.6.0/lib/  ./configure --prefix=/path_to_python-2.7.4 --enable-shared'

and then

```
make
```

I get the following:

> building '_tkinter' extension
>
> gcc -pthread -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing
>   -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DWITH_APPINIT=1 -I/usr/X11/include -I. -IInclude -I./Include -I/opt/sqlite/sqlite-3.7.16.2/include -I/opt/tk8.6.0/include -I/opt/tcl8.6.0/include -I/usr/local/include -I/opt/python/src/Python-2.7.4/Include -I/opt/python/src/Python-2.7.4 -c /opt/python/src/Python-2.7.4/Modules/_tkinter.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/opt/python/src/Python-2.7.4/Modules/_tkinter.o
>
> gcc -pthread -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3
>   -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DWITH_APPINIT=1 -I/usr/X11/include -I. -IInclude -I./Include -I/opt/sqlite/sqlite-3.7.16.2/include -I/opt/tk8.6.0/include -I/opt/tcl8.6.0/include -I/usr/local/include -I/opt/python/src/Python-2.7.4/Include -I/opt/python/src/Python-2.7.4 -c /opt/python/src/Python-2.7.4/Modules/tkappinit.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/opt/python/src/Python-2.7.4/Modules/tkappinit.o
>
> gcc -pthread -shared -L/opt/sqlite/sqlite-3.7.16.2/lib
>   -L/opt/tk8.6.0/lib/ -L/opt/tcl8.6.0/lib/ -L/opt/sqlite/sqlite-3.7.16.2/lib -L/opt/tk8.6.0/lib/ -L/opt/tcl8.6.0/lib/ -I. -IInclude -I./Include -I/opt/sqlite/sqlite-3.7.16.2/include -I/opt/tk8.6.0/include -I/opt/tcl8.6.0/include build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/opt/python/src/Python-2.7.4/Modules/_tkinter.o
>   build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/opt/python/src/Python-2.7.4/Modules/tkappinit.o
>   -L/usr/X11/lib -L/opt/sqlite/sqlite-3.7.16.2/lib -L/opt/tk8.6.0/lib/ -L/opt/tcl8.6.0/lib/ -L/usr/local/lib -L. -ltk8.6 -ltcl8.6 -lX11 -lpython2.7 -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/_tkinter.so
>
> *** WARNING: renaming "_tkinter" since importing it failed: libtk8.6.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

The odd thing is that I can see `libtk8.6.so`. It is actually right there under `/opt/tcl8.6.0/lib` as I specified with `LDFLAGS`.

Why did that compilation fail?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This problem takes place during installation in `setup.py`, when Python tries to import `_tkinter`. If you look at the function `build_extension`, there is a block that says:

```
imp.load_dynamic(ext.name, ext_filename)
```

This line tries a dynamic load of `_tkinter`  (which uses the dynamic shared library `libtk8.6.so`) . So even though the compilation/linking worked, when Python tests the module, it uses the dynamic library, and I didn't have tcl/lib nor tk/lib in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Once I added these, it all worked fine.

In summary:
I had to add the following include paths through `CPPFLAGS`

- `/path_to/sqlite3/include`
- `/path_to/tcl/include`
- `/path_to/tk/include`

the following lib paths through `LDFLAGS`

- `/path_to/sqlite3/lib`
- `/path_to/tcl/lib`
- `/path_to/tk/lib`

and the following lib paths through `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`:

- `/path_to/sqlite3/lib`
- `/path_to/tcl/lib`
- `/path_to/tk/lib`

with all this, everything worked.